# path name argument in express.static

Tags: node.js

Can I not give any random path inside express.static. like express.static('D:/abc/efg'). Should I ways give only the current working directory like express.static('__dirname'+/public)

```
var express = require('express');
app = express();
app.use(express.static('C:\Users\angela\javascripting\public'));
app.listen(8080);
```

Specifying the actual path of the current directory also does not work like above.

Comment: i think it only servers files starting from the doc root directory

Comment: You have to give the path relative to the script that you execute, so no.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```